# Problem with positioning elements using Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to place a section with 4x4 fields. Each field will hold a picture with header and paragraph centered horizontally and vertically on a picture. I would like to do that by not implementing pictures as a backgrounds for each field. I am having problem centering header and paragraph in a field.

```css
.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#pic-1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#pic-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#pic-1 h3 {
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#pic-2 {
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

#pic-3 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

#pic-4 {
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2">
  <div id="pic-1">
    <img src="./img/practise-areas.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>USLUGE KOJE PRUZAMO</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi velit, consequatur veniam dolorem eligendi tenetur ex?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pic-2">
    <img src="./img/who-we-are.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>KO SMO MI?</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="pic-3">
    <img src="./img/getting-started2.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>KONTAKTIRAJTE NAS</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="pic-4">
    <img src="./img/how-we-work.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>NAS NACIN RADA</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi velit, consequatur veniam dolorem eligendi tenetur ex?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> [...] not implementing pictures as a backgrounds

One approach which creates the effect you are looking to achieve (ie. employing marked up images as element backgrounds) is to give each image which precedes the heading and the paragraph a `position: absolute` (to take it out of document flow) and then apply the styles: `top: 0`, `left: 0` and `width: 100%`, `height: 100%`.

> I am having problem centering header and paragraph in a field.

To horizontally center the heading and the paragraph in each field, you simply need to apply the style: `text-align: center`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.container-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50%);
}

.container-2 div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-2 img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-2">
  <div id="pic-1">
    <img src="./img/practise-areas.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>USLUGE KOJE PRUZAMO</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi velit, consequatur veniam dolorem eligendi tenetur ex?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pic-2">
    <img src="./img/who-we-are.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>KO SMO MI?</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="pic-3">
    <img src="./img/getting-started2.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>KONTAKTIRAJTE NAS</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="pic-4">
    <img src="./img/how-we-work.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>NAS NACIN RADA</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi velit, consequatur veniam dolorem eligendi tenetur ex?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the width/height ratio of an image in a given field does not correspond with the width/height ratio of that field, it's (self-evidently) going to lose its ratio according to the code above. See if you can name up to three changes to the code above, any of which will mean the images do not lose their original ratio.